# Adding item id's to the js if statement

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to add some more item Id's to the follow if statement -

```
  if(engine.currentMap[toY] &&
  engine.currentMap[toY][toX] &&
  engine.currentMap[toY][toX].item > 1)
  {
  engine.keyboard.canInput = true;
  }
```

Where it says engine.currentMap[toY][toX].item > 1) I want to also add numerical Id's so it would be like .item > 1 || 45 || 78 || 45 || 23. If that kinda make scenes.

Comment: It isn't clear what you want.  Do you want to know if it's > 1 or > 45 or > 75?  That isn't useful since > 1 covers all of them.

Comment: If the id is 0, or 1 the player will move, if the id is greater than 1 the player wont move. I want to make a few expectations to that rule e.g if you meet id 44 thats okay also. I was thinking I could just adjust it to have some "OR" statements too apparently its a little harder than that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think condition `engine.currentMap[toY][toX].item > 1` is enough in the given scenario as if some thing is greater then **1 which would be the smallest value** then your condition is true and you do not need to check other conditions.

Comment: What it means in respect of my case that anything over the value of 1, it wont run something values 1 and 0 it will but I want it to run in few rare cases also e.g Id 56

Comment: why don't you assign a variable for the id and compare engine.currentMap[toY][toX].item to that.

Comment: The or subsequent conditions are not further executed when previous becomes true and any number greater then 45, 78 etc is also greater then 1 so you only need to check for 1

Answer (score 0):

If you want only those 5 items then you can use this:

```
if(engine.currentMap[toY] &&
    engine.currentMap[toY][toX] &&
    $.inArray(engine.currentMap[toY][toX].item, [0, 1, 45, 78, 23]) != -1) {
    engine.keyboard.canInput = true;
}
```

but if you want just `.item > 1 || 45 || 78 || 45 || 23` it will always return true on first check (`item > 1`), so the rest is no needed.

Answer (score 0):

To test for those additional ids, check whether `.item` *equals* one of those ids, add them to an array and then test for their existence:

```
&& ([45, 78, 45, 23].indexOf(engine.currentMap[toY][toX].item) === -1) {
```